# Angular scope present, but not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm currently working on a job-board type website as a side project. It uses Foundation (for sites) and I'm trying to deploy Angular.

I've written a very simple module and accompanying controller:

```
angular.module('jobboard', [])
.controller('genCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.data = "Hello world!";
    console.log($scope.data);
});
```

I also build a very simple template. Here's the idea:

```
<body ng-app="jobboard">
    <div ng-controller="genCtrl">
        {{data}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Some notes on this:

- I include angular and my controller script in that order in my head.
- This is what it looks like after I build with gulp. Prior, it's separated into a layout template and a page template.

So what gets me is that the `console.log()` statement works. It's just that nothing appears inside that `div`. Any ideas?

Side note: I'm familiar with Foundation for Apps, but I haven't been able to use all of the sites components with it. Those components take higher priority in this project than vanilla angular integration. If anyone knows how to non-jankily use Foundation for sites components in a Foundation for apps project, I'm all ears.

**Edit:** more details about my gulp and test-server configuration

In Foundation for sites, your project contains an `src` and a `dist` folder: the raw site files (that you edit) and the compiled site files that you move to production. I edit the files in `src`, build the project, and look at the files my server serves from `dist`.

Now, Foundation for sites doesn't ship with angular, so I installed that separately with bower. To get this into my project, I could either have it piped into my generic `app.js`, but that file ends up containing jQuery, which I like to put at the bottom of my document (which is the default location). I also prefer to put angular in the head. This is the manner in which Foundation JS files are included.

So instead of this, I have it piped into its own folder, which my document can see. Similar story with my controller script, since I don't want that built into app.js.

My guess is that somewhere along this convoluted path form `src` to `dist`, something important gets lost, I just have no idea what it could be.

Comment: its working fine. check your script which is added in your code(angularjs library). http://plnkr.co/edit/o5l40cdkFiXwAWzHTZnG this is plunker link

Comment: you might be loading HTML from the browser cache.. please try hard reloading the webpage.

Comment: No dice there. It's running off of a browser-sync & gulp-connect-php server, so I restarted that too a few times-- no luck either.  EDIT:  was running in firefox, so I tried it in chrome. Still didn't work

Comment: You should put the dom inside ng-view. Or Put JS file in the dom head.

Comment: @NeerajVerma what do you mean by that?

Comment: make sure you're included `angular-route` or `angular-ui-router`.

Comment: Please show index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code here https://jsfiddle.net/00Lfsfbj/

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</body>

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = "Hello world!";
  });
```

it is working if you select load type as no wrap in head or body, but if you select onLoad it is not working, also I tried on my machine as js in separate file and it is working so try to add your script in separate js file or inside script tag after all html components in body.

Comment: How do you select load type?

Comment: from JAVASCIPT tap beside settings icon